# How do I Launch OpenFiles.exe from Delphi XE2 ShellExecute?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

I need to launch MS Window's OpenFiles.exe from a Delphi XE2 application to export currently opened files to a text file. The normal cmd.exe syntax is something like:

```
Openfiles.exe /query /s 127.0.0.1 /nh >c:\OpenFilesExport.txt
```

Using the following code returns a successful exit code but the export file is not generated:

```
var
  exInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  exitcode: DWORD;
begin
  FillChar(exInfo, Sizeof(exInfo), 0);
  with exInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := Sizeof(exInfo);
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT;
    lpVerb := 'open';
    lpFile := Pchar('Openfiles.exe');
    lpParameters := PChar('/query /s 127.0.0.1 /nh >c:\OpenFilesOutput.txt');
    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL
  end;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@exInfo) then
  begin
    while GetExitCodeProcess(exInfo.hProcess, exitcode)
      and (exitcode = STILL_ACTIVE) do
      Application.ProcessMessages();

    CloseHandle(exInfo.hProcess);
  end
  else
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
```

I've also tried putting the cmd.exe syntax in a bat file and launching that from shellexecute and it DOES generate the file but there is no content. Running the same bat file from explorer generates the file as expected.

How can I launch Openfiles.exe successfully from ShellExecute?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the redirect, `>`, which only makes sense if you have a command interpreter. And in your code you do not. You have two options:

1. Call `ShellExecuteEx` passing a command interpreter to do the work.
2. Use `CreateProcess` to execute the other process, but pass a handle to a file as the stdout handle for the new process.

For the command interpreter option you would have a command line like this:

```
cmd /c Openfiles.exe /query /s 127.0.0.1 /nh >c:\OpenFilesExport.txt
```

The code might be like so:

```
FillChar(exInfo, Sizeof(exInfo), 0);
with exInfo do
begin
  cbSize := Sizeof(exInfo);
  fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT;
  lpFile := 'cmd.exe';
  lpParameters := '/c Openfiles.exe /query /s 127.0.0.1 /nh >c:\OpenFilesExport.txt';
  nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
end;
```

For the `CreateProcess` option you'll need to create the file with a call to `CreateFile`, and pass that handle as stdout of the new process. You'll need to make sure that the file handle is inheritable. And finally you'll need to wait on the process so that you can close the file handle.

Regarding your current code, your wait is not very pleasant. It's a busy wait that needlessly consumes CPU. You should use a blocking wait on the process handle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried solution #1 calling ShellExecuteEX and worked with the code provided but always end up with a zero length file when there should be data.

Comment: Also tried a different command using the same logic ('cmd.exe', '/C find "Test" c:\SearchIn.txt > c:\SearchOut.txt') and the export file is generated with the correct results.

Comment: `cmd /c` and a redirect of stdout works fine in my tests. I tested with `ls.exe`. I guess you just need to debug the code. I've no idea what openfiles.exe is. Is it a GUI subsystem or console subsystem app? Anyway, I honestly don't think I can offer more than what's in this answer. I'm sorry that you've not found it helpful.

Comment: The openfiles.exe app is a console app in the Windows\System32 area to query open files on the workstation. Every other console application I've tried launching with your sample code works fine. OpenFiles.exe seems to be the exception. Also tried adding the OpenFiles command to a bat file. When launched from explorer it generates the file but using shellexecute to launch the bat file it always creates a zero length export file.

Comment: Possible 32/64 bit issue. Perhaps it needs to be in syswow64 if the parent process is 32 bit. But you are doing it all wrong if you put files in the system directory. Stop doing that. Put the file somewhere else.